# Getting a "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format." on a DateTime Object insert into MySql Database

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, mvvm-light

I'm working on a App using C# with Mvvm Light and a Mysql Database.  When I do an insert into the Database with a parameter of an object being a DateTime object I am getting the following error:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value)
   at MySql.Data.Types.MySqlInt32.MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.WriteValue(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, Object val, Int32 length)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter.Serialize(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName, Int32 parameterIndex)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParameters(String sql, MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.BindParameters()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The Following is my view model code (proj.ProjectStartDate is a datetime object):

```
        DateTime startDate = projectStartDateProperty?? DateTime.Now;
        string startStr = startDate.ToString("d");
        DateTime projStart = Convert.ToDateTime(startStr);

        DateTime endDate = projectEndDateProperty ?? DateTime.Now;
        string endStr = endDate.ToString("d");
        DateTime projEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(endStr);
        proj.ProjectName = _projName;
        proj.ProjectStartDate = projStart;
        proj.ProjectEndDate = projEnd;
        proj.ProjectNotes = _projNotes;
        ProjectDbInteraction.InsertProject(_projName, proj);
```

With a break point set at the proj.ProjectEndDate the outcome is
[image]

And below is my Model code for the insert into the MySql Database:

```
    string connStr = "server=*****;database=" + projName + ";user=*****;port=*****;password=*****;";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    string queryInsertintoProjTable;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO " + projName +
        ".project(ProjectID,ProjectName,ProjectStartDate,ProjectEndDate,ProjectNotes) VALUES("
        + "(?projectid, ?projectnamecolumn,?projectstartdatecolumn,?projectenddatecolumn,?projectnotescolumn);", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?projectid", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = proj.ProjectID;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?projectnamecolumn", MySqlDbType.VarChar ).Value = proj.ProjectName;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?projectstartdatecolumn", proj.ProjectStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?projectenddatecolumn", proj.ProjectEndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?projectnotescolumn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = proj.ProjectNotes;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
```

So what is it I need to do to fix this?  This is my first time working with MySql.

Comment: From the MySQL documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html , the DateTime format should be in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Comment: Nice catch I appreciate that Saggio.

Comment: But I do have a question I can't push the string into the db.  And If I convert it back to a date time object it will convert it back to the UTC so how do I push this back into the db without this happening?

Comment: why wouldn't you be able to push the string into the DB? The error says that `the input string was not in a correct format.`  You should be able to just do `var mySQLDateTime = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: Even if the column type is datetime?

Comment: Yes it should.  take a look Derrick's (Second Answer) for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705284/format-string-in-datetime-c-sharp-to-insert-in-mysql-datetime-column

Comment: That doesn't really work for my parameterized query though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66062/discussion-between-saggio-and-crayams).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the issue.  My datetime was in fact already in the correct format.  Unfortunately when parameterizing my query the Enum MySqlDbType.DateTime was throwing a false error so I just passed in the date in the AddValue.

```
        string connStr = "server=****;database=" + projName + ";user=***;port=****;password=****;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        MySqlCommand cmd;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO " + projName +
                ".project(ProjectID,ProjectName,ProjectStartDate,ProjectEndDate,ProjectNotes) VALUES"
                + "(?projectid, ?projectnamecolumn,?projectstartdatecolumn,?projectenddatecolumn,?projectnotescolumn);", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?projectid", proj.ProjectID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?projectnamecolumn", proj.ProjectName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?projectstartdatecolumn", proj.ProjectStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?projectenddatecolumn", proj.ProjectEndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?projectnotescolumn", proj.ProjectNotes);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
```

Once I removed the Enum's from the AddWithValue it worked just fine.