# MySqlBulkLoader.Load bad behaviour for DateTime

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I've used the MySqlBulkLoader.Load() function to rapidly load a .csv on a MySql database; however, I've noticed that dates are not correct, for example the value "26/09/2017  00:00:00" written in the .csv becomes "01/01/0001 00:00:00" on the MySql table.
How can I fix this problem?

It is not a duplicated question because I've also tried to format the date, but the result is always the same.

```
// This function loads a db table into DataTable
DataTable dt = connection.getDataFromDB(nameOfTheTable);

// Now I verify the type of the column: DATETIME
Console.WriteLine("Type of the column: {0}",dt.columns["insert_date"].DataType);

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
  dr["insert_date"] = DateTime.Now;  // I tried many other ways insted of simply DateTime.Now...

// Now I call the upload function:
conn.loadDataTable(finalTable, dt);
```

Functions to create the .csv and to load the .csv on the db:

```
    public static void WriteDataTable(DataTable sourceTable, TextWriter writer, bool includeHeaders){
            if (includeHeaders){
                IEnumerable<String> headerValues = sourceTable.Columns
                    .OfType<DataColumn>()
                    .Select(column => QuoteValue(column.ColumnName));

                writer.WriteLine(String.Join(",", headerValues));
            }

            IEnumerable<String> items = null;

            foreach (DataRow row in sourceTable.Rows)
            {
                items = row.ItemArray.Select(o => QuoteValue(o?.ToString() ?? String.Empty));
                writer.WriteLine(String.Join(",", items));
            }

            writer.Flush();
        }

        private static string QuoteValue(string value)
        {
            return String.Concat("\"",
            value.Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\"");
        }

public void loadDataTable(string tableName,DataTable dt) {
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true){
            string tempCsvFileSpec = @".\dump.csv";
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tempCsvFileSpec)){
                WriteDataTable(dt, writer, true);
            }
            var msbl = new MySqlBulkLoader(connection);
            msbl.TableName = tableName;
            msbl.FileName = tempCsvFileSpec;
            msbl.FieldTerminator = ",";
            msbl.LineTerminator = "\r\n";
            msbl.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1;
            msbl.FieldQuotationCharacter = '"';
            msbl.Load();
        }
    }
```

I think it could be a formatting problem (I mean, instead of using DateTime.Now I should format the date i.e. as yyyy-dd-mm, but no way...)

**SOLVED**

The problem is not on C#'s side, but on the MySql one: in fact when the server reads the .csv it assumes that the values written in the file are well formatted, that means yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.
The solution I found is to modify the DataType of the DateTime columns in string, and then to build the value:

```
...
dt.columns["insert_date"].DataType=typeof(string);
...

char[] delimiters = { ' ','/',':'};
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows){
  string[] words= dr[s].ToString().Split(delimiters);
  dr["insert_date"] = words[2] + "-" + words[1] + "-" + words[0]+" "+words[3]+":"+words[4]+":"+words[5];
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [format string in datetime c# to insert in MYSQL datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705284/format-string-in-datetime-c-sharp-to-insert-in-mysql-datetime-column)

Comment: Sorry, but it is not a duplicated question, I've also tried the approach indicated in the other answer, but no way, it doesn't work

Comment: Have you checked in your database what is the date format being used?

Comment: theDate.ToString("dd/MM-yyyy H:mm:ss"); this will be the conversion for your date in excel.

Comment: Can you please show [MCVE] demonstrates your problem?

Comment: This looks like you try to insert some _invalid_ value for that typed column and it assigned as the default value. But again, it is hard to tell what is going on without more information.